# Line split per specific accurence of delimiters python

Tags: python, split, delimiter

I have a txt file which I should split according to specific pattern of delimiters.

**For example:**

First split should be after " " (or chr(32)) 
Second split in the same line should be "  " (or twice chr(32)), and so on.

**Below the example of the line, that I want to split:**

```
'2018-12-14 23:54:53,105 WARN  system.equipment - Timed AC is: 110.375\n'
```

I found the pattern and according to it, I want to split and set it to
 ASCII as an array. Tried to iterate for splitting, but without
 success. Thanks to everybody for your help and time!!!

```
delim_array = []
delim_array = [chr(32),chr(32),[chr(32)+chr(32)],[chr(32)+chr(45)+chr(32)]]
for j in delim_array:
    part = re.split(j,datafile[1])    #datafile is my list to split
    print (part)
```

I would like to split the list to delimiters between the parts, are
according to the delim_array:

1)'2018-12-14

2)23:54:53,105

3)WARN

4)system.equipment

5)Timed AC is: 110.375

But getting list, which split only by the first delimiter in the array.

Comment: Do all the logs have the pattern `'Timed AC'`?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. This example will do what you need.

```
import re

dd = '2018-12-14 23:54:53,105 WARN  system.equipment - Timed AC is: 110.375\n'

delim_array = [chr(32),chr(32), chr(32)+chr(32), chr(32)+chr(45)+chr(32)]
part = []
for j in delim_array:
    ap, dd = re.split(j, dd, maxsplit=1)
    part.append(ap)    #datafile is my list to split

part.append(dd.strip())
print(part)
```

This prints: `['2018-12-14', '23:54:53,105', 'WARN', 'system.equipment', 'Timed AC is: 110.375']`

The key part here to use `re.split()` with maxsplit equal to 1 ([here the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split)), so each iteration you split your line in two parts. First part is what you want to append to the `part` list, second part you keep for further splitting. So reassing the second part to same variable which holds the string (`dd` in my example). Remember after the loop to append the last `dd` obtained or it will be lost (I also strip the newline here).

If you have a datafile you need a nested loop to do this. Of course be sure that all the lines follow the same format you posted, otherwise you may get unexpected results.

```
import re

delim_array = [chr(32),chr(32), chr(32)+chr(32), chr(32)+chr(45)+chr(32)]
with open("your_file_name.txt") as datafile:
    for dd in datafile:
        part = []
        for j in delim_array:
            ap, dd = re.split(j, dd, maxsplit=1)
            part.append(ap)    #datafile is my list to split

        part.append(dd.strip())
        print(part)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Valentino! It's great explanation! But the problem, when I run the full txt file thru it (2000 lines), and check the length of the "part", I get only length of 3. I need to convert it to pandas data frame, but getting something very strange. Do you know what night be the problem?  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @MichaelK Difficult to say without looking at the full txt file. Do you have the same format for all the lines? Are there empty lines? What are the elements of your 3-long `part`?

Comment: all lines are the same. In total there are 2135 lines. I read thelines with following command:   filename = "log_2018-12-15_2359.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    datafile = f.readlines(). Than I'm using 'datafile" for working. The purpose, is to split the lines (as you helped me) and convert it to dataframe.  My part line, looks as follows: ['2018-12-15', '00:00:07,401', 'WARN', ' Command', "[EventDistributorad]  command 27ms to complete)"]. This line I want to store it as a dataframe. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Seems that the splitting is done correctly. `part` is a 5 length list. So the question is how to store it in a dataframe? Pandas? If so you might edit the original question with the proper tag or open a new question related to "how add a line to a dataframe". But try first to look for already existing questions for this, is a common task.